# How to find out what is adding bogus keys to the registry?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, monitoring

I've been happily running Windows 7 on my ultrabook for over a year now. It's stable, fast, everything pretty much works as it should, except something is adding randomly named keys to the registry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER.
So occasionally I go in and delete all the $äe, bløþ¶Ŗx, etc. keys with a sense of impending doom as I try to not delete actual valid trees.
Is there any way to find out what is creating these bogus, annoying, possibly dangerous keys to the registry?

Comment: Have you check for malware?  Try using something like Combofix, [link]http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/

Comment: FYI: you can export the keys to a file before removing them. In case you need to put them back. :)

Comment: I believe TeaTimer will alert you to any program making a registry change. TeaTimer is a component of Spybot S&D. Other than actually catching the bad actor, you won't find a lot of historical metadata about registry keys to audit. you could always lock down that section of the registry and see what complains, but be extra careful to record what you did so you can undo it later.

Comment: @techie007: I do keep complete registry backups just in case, but these specific keys really don't need saving. :-)

Comment: @StBlade: Perhaps I've become a bit complacent relying on MSE to do most of the heavy lifting. Will have a scan or two.

Comment: @FrankThomas: That's a very good idea, haven't used Spybot in a number of years, so I totally forgot about TeaTimer. Could you consider posting as an answer so that I may upvote and possibly accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the SysInternals tool [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). It's great for watching what's happening to the file system/registry (although there is so much information you'll need to think up a useful filter to weed out 'normal' activity).

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows
>   real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity.

Comment: If the TeaTimer option doesn't work out I will certainly give this a try.

Comment: Actually, I got a hit pretty quickly by looking through the Registry Summary. `LWEMon.exe` (a Logitech Wingman supporting program) appears to be accessing these weird keys. Will follow up with TeaTimer to be sure, but it looks as though we may have found the perpetrator.

Comment: After having disabled the autostart for LWEMon.exe, the registry keys have stopped popping up. Problem solved. Thank you very much! Accepted.